# Pandas Data Frame Data Type Recognized as object and not Numeric

Tags: python

I looked at the data and it seemed numeric?. I wrote a little loop and it displays values like 84 as not int, or 214.56 as not float. It just seems broken. Do Pandas Data Frames just have a randomness to them?

My data set has this shape:

(622380, 45)

When I isolate the column it still has a problem. But when I shorten the column it seems to be OK.

Is there a length at which the data frame becomes unstable? Can I force the data types?

Comment: Here is some data.

Comment: date,1,2.0000
3/18/2014,84,84.4455
    '3/19/2014,217,216.7926
    3/20/2014,82,81.7377
    3/21/2014,57,56.5015'

Comment: for val in model_data['1']:
    if not isinstance(val, int):
        print('Error: val = {!r}'.format(val))

Comment: No, pandas has no randomness to it. If the shortened column is interpreted as integer but the full column is not, that probably means that some value in the column cannot be converted to an integer. Maybe a `null` or a `N/A` or something like that? Or maybe there is a `,` in a row that is not escaped correctly and pandas does not know where one field ends and the next one begins.

Comment: To force types, use [`pandas.DataFrame.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html).

Answer (score 0):

After digging around some more..  I found a better way to debug the data.
    pd.to_numeric(model_data['Value2SPY'])

Did the trick because when it bombed out it told me the line item..

ValueError: Unable to parse string "#DIV/0!" at position 241396

The code I was using before "if not isinstance(val, int):" just was a bad method to debug the data...